# How can I get PHP to connect locally to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to test a PHP website locally on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, but I'm having trouble connecting to MySQL database using `mysqli_connect()`.

I have Apache 2.4 running with `mod_php7.0`.
I installed the Ubuntu package `php7.0-mysql`.
Accessing a `php.info()` file at a localhost address in the same directory as the website indicates that my php.ini file is `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`.
In that file, I removed the comment from the line `;extension=php_mysqli.dll`.

The file I'm trying to access contains the line

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password","db_name");
```

When I try to access the site, I get the error

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"
```

with reference to the line above.

I have MySQL running locally with the given user, password, and database defined.  I've tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, but the error is the same.

The error appears to be that PHP can't make a local connection to MySQL.  How can I figure out what's wrong?

**Edit** To give more context, I'm trying to create a localhost version of a website that works on its production/dev servers.  As far as I can tell, I've recreated all relevant aspects of the server setup, but obviously I've missed something.

The biggest difference between the local setup and production/dev version is that I have PHP7 locally but PHP5.5.9 on production/dev.  My best guess at this point is that this difference is what's responsible for the localhost failure, but I don't know enough about PHP to narrow down what it might be.

Comment: check mysql, is it connected? check port also

Comment: Try accessing mysql from terminal using `mysql -hlocalhost -udb_user -ppassword` , and see if you can access

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya That works.  I can enter the MySQL shell using it.

Comment: @devpro The MySQL server is running, if that's what you're asking.  How should I check the port?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to connect to MySQL database on localhost.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysql-password";
$dbname = "database-name";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```